# Layout background eats all the memory

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, drawable

in my Android app, I have a layout with a background:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    >
...
```

The background image is png (240x400 for ldpi, 320x480 for mdpi, etc...)

**I tried using a jpg, but it looked awful so switched it back to png.**

When I change the orientation, it works fine a couple of times, and then the app forces to close throwing the following error:

```
dalvikvm-heap(16260): 148960-byte external allocation too large for this process.
VM won't let us allocate ... bytes

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo...
```

So, I thought I could fix it just by unbinding the drawables in the onDestroy method, right?
Well, nope... I have the following method in my onDestroy:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.frame));

        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if(view==null)
            return;
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            try{
                ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
            }catch(UnsupportedOperationException mayHappen) {
                Log.e("Error:", mayHappen.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make this work? I checked already for memory leaks, but nothing...

Comment: Images take up a lot of memory, and Android has very little available. As a general rule try to avoid them whenever possible, especially for backgrounds. This isn't an answer so I'll leave it as a comment.

Comment: I don't think onDestroy() fires for screen re-orientation, so that code would not happen when you want it to.

Comment: @goldilocks onDestroy() is called when the screen is rotated. Verifying this is a simple enough: ` @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  Log.v("Test", "onDestroy");
  super.onDestroy();
 }
`

Comment: have you dumped the hprof for your app and checked?

Comment: @Sam: okay, I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @goldilocks: onDestroy() is usually called when the screen is rotated, though I don't think it's actually part of the contract.  It may or may not be safe to assume it would always be the case.

Comment: @Perroloco: How big is the image that you're trying to show as a background.  You don't need to unbind drawables when they're attached to Views. Especially when the app is being destroyed.

Comment: are you sure its due to the image , just remove it run and your app and try to reproduce your problem so that it can  be confirmed.

Comment: the image has different sizes for different screens. 240x400 for ldpi, 320x480 for mdpi, etc.

Now, by using the unbindDrawables method, it doesn't crash so often, but it still does.@SunnyKumarAditya I removed the background and it doesn't crash without it.

@nandeesh what do you mean with hprof?

Comment: Check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). Just before you think it will crash, dump hprof data and see what objects are taking up memory.